# Install 2 linux distros in 2 separate disks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04, system-installation

My computer has 2 HDD disks. One with 80 GB and the other with 160 GB.

I have already install Debian 7.0 Wheezy in the 80 GB disk and i am **planning** to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS into the 160 GB.

I don't know what i have to do about the grub configuration and what to do.

I wrote this question to ask you about working between 2 linux distros.

All the tutorials are wroten only for Windows and linux, so i need to know if i have to do something cause i want to use the two operation systems without loosing the one of them.

Comment: When installing Trusty point GRUB installation to the first HDD (sda1) & it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i insert the cdrom for installation, i selected the second disk ( 80 GB ) to install ubuntu.

When grub installation started it recognised Debian as an exist linux operating system.

### Now at boot it recognized two linux  os as i asked for.